# Ordenando uma lista de objetos por data

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho uma lista de objetos e cada objeto dessa lista tem um atributo que é uma data, no formato de string mesmo. Como eu faço para ordenar essa lista de objetos por essa data?

Comment: Usando a ordem de data ou de string? Sabe que a ordem vai ficar errada tendo este atributo como uma string, né?

Comment: Eu preciso que ela fique ordenada por data. Seria melhor eu usar o objeto de data do python na hora de preencher o atributo?

Comment: Não sei, só você pode saber isso. Se você precisa dela como `Date` na maioria do tempo, deveria estar usando como `Date`, se precisa como `string` sempre e só precisa que seja `Date` na hora de ordenar, talvez exista uma solução melhor. Dependendo da quantidade de dados, é até considerável converter antes de ordenar neste último caso. Mas tudo é relativo...

Comment: Acho que me expressei errado.

Comment: Entendi, minha situação é:
Eu pego essa informação de data direto de um arquivo txt e coloco ela em outro aquivo txt só que em um layout diferente.
Me foi solicitado que eu ordene essas informações por data antes que eu grave no novo layout. 
Nesse cenário, para fazer essa ordenação, é melhor usar como Date ou como String

Answer (score 0):

Pode deixar sua classe comparável com outra através do atributo data.

```
    from functools import total_ordering
    from datetime import date

    @total_ordering
    class obj:
        def __init__(self, dia, mes, ano):
            self.data = date(ano, mes, dia)

        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.data == other.data
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return self.data < other.data
```

Ou pode usar direto pelo date, ele aceita diretamente comparação.

```
    >>>data1 = date(2012, 12, 1)
    >>>data2 = date(1999, 10, 1)
    >>>data1 > data2
```

Como o objeto agora pode ser comparável com outro, podemos usar um sorted, para ordenar uma lista, com n-objetos, ou qualquer outro algoritmo de ordenação.
Ex:

```
   a = obj(1, 12, 1990)
   b = obj(1, 12, 1991)
   c = obj(1, 12, 1992)

   l = [b, a, c]

   r = sorted(l)

   print(r[1].data)
```

Comment: A resposta está incompleta. Com as informações dadas ainda é impossível realizar o que o autor precisa. Indique o que fazer a seguir. Digo, um exemplo de algoritmo de ordenação ou se existe alguma função a ser utilizada.

Comment: No meu caso a data é um atributo de um objeto, existe uma lista desse mesmo objeto e eu quero ordenar essa lista pelo atributo de data do objeto. Mas sua resposta me ajudou a ver que independente do que for feito, é muito melhor usar o objeto Data mesmo.